# Controller event listener's object

Tags: php, symfony

In the `onKernelController` method I get really huge object passed as an argument - I can guess how it affects the performance of my application.

How can I check if the controller implements an interface inside the event listener class?

```
public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    $controller = $event -> getController()[0];
    if ($controller instanceof IInterface) // doesn't work
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what's `$controller`?

Comment: Called controller object.

Comment: Why are you using the array syntax on getController?  Only going to be one controller per event. http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Event/FilterControllerEvent.html#method_getController

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to check if class of your object implements an interface, [instanceof](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php) must work.

Answer (score 0):

In php Objects passes by references, actually passes by values but the variable holds the object reference point. So you shouldn't be concerned about to passing this to the event listener if it will already instantianed by dependency injection after event listener, I mean when actions work. So you shouldn't be concerned.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem related to this, my solution was:

```
public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    $controller = $event->getController();

    if (is_array($controller)) {
        $controller = reset($controller);
    }

    if ($controller instanceof IInterface)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Sometimes - I can't remember exactly when - method "getController" was returning an array with second entry being action.